# Modifying a superclass's property

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to make the UIViewController view class be a scrollView. How do i do this?

Comment: I had to read three times and still don't get it. You're obviously not a 'noob' so is this qustion serious? Class of one object is not it's property and in this case you won't be able even to typecast this view unless it already is a UIScrollView or it's descendant. Maybe it's just awquard articulation. What exactly would you like to do?

Comment: I have  UIViewController, which has a UIView as a property, called 'view'. I want to make this property into a UIScrollView. The problem with just doing alloc on it as a UIScrollView is that in future it won't give me UIScrollView coding suggestions for it, and will always think of it as a UIView.

Comment: Aha, ok. That's easy. See answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just initialize the view to an `UIScrollView` in the `-loadView` method (you need to override it).

```
- (void)loadView {
  self.view = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:...];
  // do other init stuff;
}
```

You don't need to call `[super loadView]`, it would only allocate a default `UIView` instance and assign it to `view`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not:

```
@implementation MyScrollViewController
...
...
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //configure my scrollview (self.view).  This may require you to cast your self.view to UIScrollView.
}
-(void)loadView
{
   UIScrollView *sv = [UIScrollView alloc] init] autorelease]; //will be retained by self.view
   self.view = sv ;
}
...
...
@end
```